# Cloudrail API File Migration

Tags: c#, migration, cloudrail

I cannot clearly see it on the website but via the CloudRail API, I am able to migrate files to another cloud server from a user's Dropbox, Google Drive, OneDrive, etc.? Is it a cloud file migration API?

Answer (score 1):

CloudRail enables you, among other things, to upload and download files to and from Dropbox, Google Drive etc. in an abstracted, uniform manner.
It is an SDK based solution currently available for Android, Java, iOS and Node.js.
It is not a migration solution but it can make building one much easier since you'd only have to take care of UI and logic.

Source: I am working for CloudRail

Comment: thanks for the information, is there an SDK releasing for UWP? Could Cloudrail execute a program to prepare migrated media for Dash streaming and then serve it to an app? Thanks.